# What is the preferred way (better style) to define a method in one line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

What is the better style:

```
def method; some code end
```

or

```
def method() some code end
```

and why?

Comment: If you ask me, the preferred way is to define it in several lines (I'd even say at least 3).

Comment: I'd recommend reading through some of the style guides mentioned in the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616037/ruby-coding-style-guidelines

Answer (score 9):

The preferred way is to **not** define a method in one line, as @Romain said.

```
def method
  some code
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Some people use `{}` instead of `begin; end` when writing blocks on only one line.

Maybe this suits your needs:

```
class A
    define_method(:method_name) { |arg1, arg2| do_something }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a method on one line should only be done in documentation, otherwise split it onto three lines:

```
def method
    some code
end
```

If you find that you have a lot of one-liner methods (i.e. getters & setters) there could be many metaprogramming techniques (such as using `define_method`) to reduce duplication. For instance, you can use `:attr_accessor` to define many getters & setters:

```
class Person
    # defines name, name=, age, age=, ...
    attr_accessor :name, :age, :blood_type
end
```

[Here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/112272) is a ruby forum that talks about this. I also highly recommend reading [Metaprogramming Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476). It has many goodies like 3 or 4 ways to solve your problem as well as many other techniques to reduce duplication.